# Can I delete the data partition from my hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, storage, window, android-x86

I have a 500gb hard drive and I am trying to install Android x86 on it, alongside Windows and Ubuntu. A long time ago (before I had Ubuntu) I had to get my motherboard replaced, so somewhere along that process, the technician made a Data partition on my hard drive that's about 200gb (I shrank it to about 160 before installing ubuntu). It only has about half a gigabyte (maybe less) of data on it. It's NTFS. Can I safely delete it so I have more space to install Android and maybe expand Ubuntu?

Comment: You absolutely can delete the partition if you want.

Comment: You really need to provide more information to give a meaningful answer. Based on what you've described it seems perfectly fine to delete it and then expend another partition into it or make a new partition there. But without a current partition table that advice isn't very useful.

Comment: Screen shot of the disk in Disk Management would be nice.